# Failing to connect Azure CentOS VM via Sentora FTP

Tags: centos, ftp, azure

I created CentOS 6.5 and I installed Sentora 1.0.3 on Azure VM Service. But i couldn't make a connection with Sentora FTP account.

I'm trying to connect Sentora ftp account with FileZilla.

I get this warnings:

```
Server sent passive reply with unroutable address. Using server address instead.

Error:          Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity  
Error:          Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

**Azure Inbound security rules:**

```
NAME    SOURCE  DESTINATION SERVICE ACTION
Tcp-1024    Any Any Custom (TCP/1024)
FTP Any Any FTP (TCP/21)
FTP-UDP Any Any Custom (UDP/21)
FTPData Any Any Custom (TCP/20)
dynamic-passive Any Any Dynamic ports (TCP/60000-65100)
default-allow-ssh   Any Any SSH (TCP/22)
default-allow-http  Any Any Custom (ANY/80)
default-allow-smtp  Any Any SMTP (TCP/25)
default-allow-dns   Any Any Custom (ANY/53)
default-allow-POP3  Any Any Custom (ANY/110)
default-allow-IMAP  Any Any Custom (ANY/143)
```

**CentOS iptables list :**

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpts:65000:65100 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ftp 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:bootpc 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

if I add all ports Inbound security rules, connection is fine i can connect than but when i add individual ports needed by sentora, connection fails again.

I have tired many methods but can't manage to establish successful ftp  connection.

Any help appreciated.